# XBIM - how to get rotation of an object (flowterminal)

Tags: rotation, ifc, xbim

I am trying to get the rotation of an object (flowterminal) from a IFC-file using XBIM

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyBy5.png)

i can not seem to find a property, so it seems that the rotation needs to be calculated

this is what i have so far:

```
        For Each flowTerminal As IIfcFlowTerminal In flowTerminals


            'insertionpoints
            Dim objectPlacement As IIfcLocalPlacement = flowTerminal.ObjectPlacement
            Dim relativeplacement As IIfcAxis2Placement3D = objectPlacement.RelativePlacement
            Dim location As IIfcCartesianPoint = relativeplacement.Location

            'rotatie van de inbouwdelen
            Dim localPlacement As IIfcLocalPlacement = DirectCast(flowTerminal.ObjectPlacement, IIfcLocalPlacement)

            ' Extract the transformation matrix from the local placement
            Dim transform As XbimMatrix3D = localPlacement.RelativePlacement.ToMatrix3D

            Dim Xdiff As Double = Math.Abs(transform.M11 - transform.M21)
            Dim Ydiff As Double = Math.Abs(transform.M12 - transform.M22)

            'Extract rotation angles from the transformation matrix
            Dim rollAngle As Double = Math.Atan2(Ydiff, Xdiff)

            'Convert angles to degrees
            rollAngle = rollAngle * (180.0 / Math.PI)
            MsgBox(rollAngle)



        Next
```

Comment: Roy, can you edit to show what you're seeing and what you'd want to see? It looks like you're only looking at rotation around the Z axis (i.e. a 2D rotation). Is that what you want? Have you see the Quaternion support in `XbimMatrix3D` - https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimEssentials/blob/ac8b9092b87ae401d91d53578388b2b746c26852/Xbim.Common/Geometry/XbimMatrix3D.cs#L1294? Also be aware that LocalPlacement is relative to the the parent context (e.g. The BuildingStorey, Building and Site). See https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4/FINAL/HTML/link/ifclocalplacement.htm

Comment: Andy, Yes i'm only seeking the rotation around the Z-axis (2D rotation). do you maybe have an example code in VB.net?